# Jquery Search + MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, search

Im inspired to replicate this feature in my site.

[This](http://ajaxdump.com/?0DPIbJoN)

The backend is written in php, im not familiar with it. Would really appreciate some guidiance on it. Any sample code or pseudocode will be greatly appreciated with respect to .NET MVC3

Currently, im consuming a search webservice that returns an object based on searched title.

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? What difficulties did you encounter? What is your question?

Comment: Something went wrong with the link?

Comment: What is your answer? How to rewrite php site to mvc with search on jquery?

Comment: Not only with the link. With the question as well. The OP forgot to show what he has tried so far.

Comment: wow chill, im getting the sensing that im getting flamed! Edited the link, sorry about it. Okok, in the process of working on it, will post up soon

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is write a controller method that will return json and take query string as a parameter. Then use jQueryUI autocomplete to write the client side.

From jQueryUI example:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/YourController/YourMethod",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    });
```

ASP.NET MVC method:

```
public JsonResult YourMethod(string term)
{
    return JSON(new {id=1, value="asdf"});
}
```

This is an example code (it has not been compiled nor tested, so it most probably has issues that you will need to resolve)

Answer (score 1):

The backend does this thing:

1. The actual page is sending a AJAX request to

   http://yourpage/givemeresults.aspx?q=my_keyword

like this:

```
 $("#mytextbox").bind("change",function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val())=!""){
        $.getJSON("http://yourpage/givemeresults.aspx?q=" + $(this).val(), function(data){
            //add data to overlaying div and show it
        });
    }    
 });
```

1. The backend page "givemeresults.aspx" is getting the "q" value from the querystring and queries the database like this :

   Select name from mytable where name like "?%", ? = q value from querystring
2. When the results arrive, It builds a JSON array from the results and then puts it on the screen.
3. Your actual page gets the result and decodes it, then builds the list. and shows the user.

This is the working style of autocompletes.

And the differences of the script at the link you gave:

- This uses http://qpoit.com/marcofolio_demo/apple_search/rpc.php to POST (not GET)
- The results are not JSON array, directly the contents of the list. It builds the list server-side.

The others are the same.

Need something else?

Answer (score 0):

My answer of trying. It works.

The Script

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
{
// Safely inject CSS3 and give the search results a shadow
var cssObj = { 'box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // Added when CSS3 is standard
    '-webkit-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px', // Safari
    '-moz-box-shadow' : '#888 5px 10px 10px'}; // Firefox 3.5+
$("#suggestions").css(cssObj);

// Fade out the suggestions box when not active
 $("input").blur(function(){
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
 });
});

function lookup(inputString) {
if(inputString.length == 0) {
    $('#suggestions').fadeOut(); // Hide the suggestions box
} else {

$.post("/Store/Search", { videoTitle: inputString }, 

function (data) { // Do an AJAX call
        $('#suggestions').fadeIn(); // Show the suggestions box
        $('#suggestions').html(data); // Fill the suggestions box
    });
}
}
```

The Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Search(string videoTitle)
    {
        List<Searchable> searchedList = new List<Searchable>();
        var auth = new Authentication() { Email = "smu@smu.com", Password = "test" };
        var videoList = server.Search(auth, videoTitle);

        return Json(videoList.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The View

```
   <form id="searchform">
<div>
    What are you looking for?
    <input type="text" size="30" id="inputString" name="inputString" onChange="lookup(this.value);" />
</div>
<div id="suggestions">
</div>
</form>
```

Theres no model because im consuming a webservice method Search that returns a list of objects.

Thanks, hope the above codes will help anyone who wants to do the same.